# How do I check in pages that were left checked out after being imported using Content Porter?

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2009

I was importing some pages to a website publication using Content Porter.

The import was successful but when I opened content manager explorer I found some pages from the import checked out with my username. I tried to check in those through CME but the check in option is not enabled.

How can I check in these pages?

Comment: Other reasons for not seeing the check in option (for an item you've checked out) is being in a child publication for an item or not having write permissions or component editing rights for that given environment and/or containing organizational item (folder or structure group). Also double check you're in the containing publication, perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will happen whenever you import an item that *must* go through workflow according to the target server's configuration.

In your specific case, it looks like the Structure Groups that you imported your pages into have a linked workflow process, and - since workflow is enforced by the core - creating those items started the workflow.

There is no way around this, you will need to go through the workflow process. If you don't have workflow defined in the Structure Groups, then something weird is happening, but I'm about 99% sure that this is the case.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**
Please see [Nuno's answer](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/1409/71) regarding Workflow and Content Porter.  Only if your Pages are not subject to Workflow does this answer apply....

---

It is highly unusual for the Content Port to show as successful but still leave items checked-out.

If you are unable to check-in these pages, then I would try the following:

1. Ensure that the Pages are actually checked-out by opening one of them and checking the status in the 'Info' tab (including the 'locked since' field).  If they are not actually checked-out (but are showing as such) then try clearing your browser cache.
2. Make sure that you are viewing the Page in its root Publication (where it was created) - You cannot check-in a shared item from a child Publication.
3. Try checking-in the Pages from the `My Tasks` -> `Checked-out Items` section
   [image]

If you are still having problems, then you may want to consider rolling-back your Content Port and/or contacting Tridion Support.

Answer (score 1):

That's right, items were checked out because they underwent the workflow. I resolved that issue. Also I have thought of using below mentioned query to check in the item:-

```
update ITEM_REFERENCE_PUBLICATIONS set ITEM_LOCK=0,ITEM_LOCK_DATE=null,ITEM_LOCK_OWNER=null    where ITEM_LOCK=1  and ITEM_REFERENCE_ID=19882
```